# Save search term on refresh React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

I am simply looking to save and restore a search term(form data) when a page is refreshed/reloaded. I have tried several solutions to no avail.

Flow:  A user submits a search term and is taken to Spotify to retrieve an accessToken, if it is not already available. The initial page is refreshed once the accessToken is retrieved, but the search must be re-entered. This is not good UX.

I concluded that Web Storage was they way to go, of course it is not the only route. I am not sure if this is something that should be relegated to Lifecycle methods: **componentDidMount()** & **componentDidUpdate()**. Perhaps that is overkill? In any event, I attempted to employ both **localStorage** and **sessionStorage**. My implementation is obviously off as I am not getting the expected result. React dev tools displays the state of the SearchBar term, but it is not being saved. Also of note is the following: React dev tools shows that the onSubmit event handler is registering as **bound () {}** instead of the expected **bound handleInitialSearchTerm() {}**. The console also shows that there are no errors.

No third-party libraries please.

**SearchBar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "./SearchBar.css";

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: this.handleInitialSearchTerm
    };
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    this.handleInitialSearchTerm = this.handleInitialSearchTerm.bind(this);
    this.setSearchTerm = this.setSearchTerm.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchOnEnter = this.handleSearchOnEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInitialSearchTerm = (event) => {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.term) {
        return localStorage.term
      } else {
      return this.setSearchTerm(String(window.localStorage.getItem("term") || ""));
      }  
    }
  };
  
  setSearchTerm = (term) => {
    localStorage.setItem("term", term);
      this.setState({ term: term });
  }

  search() {
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
  }

  handleSearchOnEnter(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.search();
    }
  }

  handleTermChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      term: event.target.value
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <input
          placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist"
          onChange={this.handleTermChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleSearchOnEnter}
          onSubmit={this.handleInitialSearchTerm}
        />
        <button className="SearchButton" onClick={this.search}>
          SEARCH
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**Motify.js**

```
let accessToken;
const clientId = "SpotifyCredentialsHere"; 
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/";
const CORS = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"; // Bypasses CORS restriction

const Motify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    // if accessToken does not exist check for a match
    const windowURL = window.location.href;

    const accessTokenMatch = windowURL.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);

    const expiresInMatch = windowURL.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
    
    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
    
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1]; //[0] returns the param and token

      const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);

      window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = "", expiresIn * 1000);

      // This clears the parameters, allowing us to grab a new access token when it expires.
      window.history.pushState("Access Token", null, "/"); 
      return accessToken;
    } else {

      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
},
  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Motify.getAccessToken();
    const url = `${CORS}https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`;
    
    return fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
    }).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(jsonResponse => {
      if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
        return [];
      }
      return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
        id: track.id,
        name: track.name,
        artist: track.artists[0].name,
        album: track.album.name,
        uri: track.uri,
        preview_url: track.preview_url
      }));
    })
  }

...
```

Comment: `localStorage.term`?? try `localStorage.getItem( ..`  - value not saved on updates/changes - `setSearchTerm` not called from handlers

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code I have added.

Changes I did are below:

1)

```
this.state = {
        term: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('term')) || '';
      };
```

2. ```
    setSearchTerm = (term) => {
               this.setState({
                   term: term
                 },
                 () => {
                   localStorage.setItem('term', JSON.stringify(this.state.term)));
               }
   ```

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./SearchBar.css";

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        term: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('term')) || '';
      };
      this.search = this.search.bind(this);
      this.handleInitialSearchTerm = this.handleInitialSearchTerm.bind(this);
      this.setSearchTerm = this.setSearchTerm.bind(this);
      this.handleSearchOnEnter = this.handleSearchOnEnter.bind(this);
      this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInitialSearchTerm = (event) => {
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.term) {
          return localStorage.term
        } else {
          return this.setSearchTerm(String(window.localStorage.getItem("term") || ""));
        }
      }
    };

    setSearchTerm = (term) => {
      this.setState({
          term: term
        },
        () => {
          localStorage.setItem('term', JSON.stringify(this.state.term)));
      }

      search() {
        this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
      }

      handleSearchOnEnter(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.search();
        }
      }

      handleTermChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          term: event.target.value
        });
      }


      render() {
        return ( <
          div className = "SearchBar" >
          <
          input placeholder = "Enter A Song, Album, or Artist"
          onChange = {
            this.handleTermChange
          }
          onKeyDown = {
            this.handleSearchOnEnter
          }
          onSubmit = {
            this.handleInitialSearchTerm
          }
          /> <
          button className = "SearchButton"
          onClick = {
            this.search
          } >
          SEARCH <
          /button> <
          /div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default SearchBar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If it is in hooks i would have done like below:

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useRef,
} from 'react';
  

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('prevCount') === null) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return localStorage.getItem('prevCount');
    }
  });

  const countRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    countRef.current = value;
    if (countRef.current) {
      localStorage.setItem('prevCount', countRef.current);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('prevCount', 0);
    }
  });

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setValue((value) => +value + 1);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    if (value === 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      setValue((value) => value - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <label className="counterLabel">Simple Counter</label>
      <button
        className="button"
        onClick={handleIncrement}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
      <span className="count">{value}</span>
      <button
        className="button"
        onClick={handleDecrement}
      >
        Decrement
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So what the above code is doing is that when we inititalize the state value we first check the localStorage , if "term" has value in localStorage we will use that value or else an empty string is initialized.

Using callback of setState inside the method setSearchTerm we set the term value immediately

Answer (score 0):

Try the useLocalStorage hook to save search client side.

```
      // useLocalStorage Hook to persist values client side
      function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
        // State to store our value
        // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
        const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
          if (typeof window === "undefined") {
            return initialValue;
          }
    
          try {
            // Get from local storage by key
            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
            // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
          } catch (error) {
            // If error also return initialValue
            console.log(error);
            return initialValue;
          }
        });
    
        // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
        // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
        const setValue = (value) => {
          try {
            // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
            const valueToStore =
              value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
            // Save state
            setStoredValue(valueToStore);
            // Save to local storage
            if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
              window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
            }
          } catch (error) {
            // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
            console.log(error);
          }
        };
    
        return [storedValue, setValue];
      }
```

credit: Brandon Baars